# Sketch the level curves of the function $f(x,y) = (x+y)^4$

Tags: calculus, functions, graphing-functions

My attempt:

Let $$z = (x+y)^4 \iff  \pm  \sqrt[4]{z} = (x+y)$$

Since $z$ is a constant, $\sqrt[4]{z}$ will also be a constant.

$$(x+y) = \sqrt[4]{z} = c \iff y = -x + c$$

So the contour plot will look something like this:[image]

The question also says, "From your sketch, determine whether $f$ has a maximum, a minimum or neither at the point (0,0)".

My answer would be "neither", since the point (0,0) is just a single point - it is not a part of a line or curve.

Comment: Careful. $f(x,y) \geq 0$ for all $(x,y)$. And in fact the minimum of $f$ is zero, which is attained everywhere on the line $x + y = 0$. The origin lies on that line.

Comment: It might help to note that $f = g \circ h$, where $h(x,y) = x+y, g(z) = z^4$. Clearly $g(z) \ge 0 $ and it achieves a minimum at $z=0$. Since the range of $h$ is the whole real line, it includes $z=0$, hence $f$ has a minimum there. Any points $(x,y)$ that satisfy $h(x,y) = 0$ are also minimisers.